# Django: Aggregate and Sum with a join with another table without the forign key constraint

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

Here is my models.py file.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User   
class image(models.Model):
    name  = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    src = models.URLField()
    alt  = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    points = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    id  = models.CharField(max_length = 200, primary_key = True)
    hotelId = models.IntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name   
class imagescore(models.Model): 
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    image_id = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    score = models.IntegerField(default = 1)
    createdTime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add =True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        if self.score < 0: 
            status = " rejected "
        else: 
            status = "approved"
        return (self.user+ status+ image_id)
        pass
```

I would like to pass on to my template a table that is a result of the SQL Query:

> ```
>     select  ei.id,ei.src, ei.hotelId , sum(score) 
> from eyeballing_image ei LEFT join eyeballing_imagescore eis on ei.id = eis.image_id
>
> where user_id = request.user.id and  ei.hotelId = 56565 
> group by 
> ei.id,ei.src, ei.hotelId
> ```

My app name is eyeballing. O tried using joins and filters bot i couldn't make it work.

Additionally, i tried making the sum(score) part into a separate dict and check the same in the template. Didn't work

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post some query code?

Comment: it was some random stuff I tried to make a poc in the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Your query has two problems, one in column name `hotelId`. you must use it in query in this way `ei."hotelId"`.

Other problem is in condition `user_id = request.user.id` because you have not `request` in sql and you must replace it with a value.

Maybe another problem is in `return (self.user + status + image_id)` that must be `return (self.user + self.status + self.image_id)`.